# Tensorflow Failed to get device attribute 13 for device 0

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I know that there are similar question on stackoverflow, but those answers are useless in my case.
I have:

1. Tensorflow 2.1.0
2. CUDA 10.1
3. CUDNN 7.6.5
4. Nvidia GeForce 920M (DRIVER UPGRADED TO LAST VERSION)

I tried some code snipped like:

```
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
```

And others similar code BUT NOTHING.

Full error:  Attempting to fetch value instead of handling error Internal: failed to get device att
ribute 13 for device 0: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN: unknown error

Comment: Install [CUDA toolkit 11.0](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11.0-download-archive) and reboot after sudo apt-get install nvidia-modprobe. Thanks